# $\{\{1\},\emptyset\}\setminus \{\emptyset\}=$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we find the set difference between the set $\{\{1\},\emptyset\}$ and the set $\{\emptyset\}$, what do we get? My best guess is $\{\{1\}\}$.

Comment: It is correct .

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Thinking $\{1\}$ and $\emptyset$ are just $2$ elements rather than $2$ sets, it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're correct: $A\setminus B=\{x: x\in A\text{ and } x\notin B\}$.

Let $A=\{\{1\},\emptyset\},B=\{\emptyset\}$ as $\{1\}$ is in $A$ but not in $B$, it is in $A\setminus B$, but as $\emptyset\in B$, it's not in $A\setminus B$, thus $A\setminus B= \{\{1\}\}$.